# Two questions about these notations/operations in the covariant derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

For two vector fields **V** and **T** we can take the covariant derivative:

$$\nabla_V T=\nabla_{V^\mu \hat e_{\mu}}T$$

$$=V^\nu \nabla_{\hat e_\nu}T$$

What exactly are we doing when we take the vector component $V^\nu$ out of the covarient derivative here?

Secondly, when we define the action of the covariant derivative on scalars, in my head this should effectively be the directional derivative of a the scalar field. However I see it written, for a vector field X, like this:

$$\nabla_X (f)=X(f)$$

I don't understand what this means, what exactly does it mean to "act" on a scalar with a vector field in this way? Is it using the fact that vectors can be written as directional derivatives? If so could someone make this notation a bit clearer?

Comment: linearity? $\nabla_{a+b}=\nabla_a+\nabla_b$ and $\nabla_{\lambda a}=\lambda \nabla_a$.

Comment: for the first question we are basically doing a basis decomposition of the operator $\nabla_V$, so what we are saying is basically that it is equal to a linear combination of the operators $\nabla_{\hat{e}_\nu}$ and the components $V^\nu$ in the formula are just the coefficients of this expansion.

Comment: for the second question it all boils down to definitions. Usually the Tangent space on a manifold $M$ is defined as the space of all the functions from $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that adhere to Leibniz's derivation law (the product law for derivatives). I understand it is not a very intuitive way to define it and there is no simple way to convince you that this definition is good other than directing you to a differential geometry textbook sadly, you'll have to take my word on that one.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that the notation $\nabla_i$ for instance is a shorthand way of effectively writing $\frac{\nabla}{\nabla x^{i}}$ in the same way we would write $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^{i}}}$ in the shorthand $\partial_{i}$?

Comment: With this definition then the expression says exactly what you were expecting, namely that the action of the covariant derivative on a scalar field is just the action of the vector $X$ on the field, and that action happens to actually be the directional derivative of the field along $X$.

Just fancy notation that actually makes the whole thing really clear for people who like algebra. But fancy notation nonetheless

Comment: sorry i was finishing the comment and didn't reply to your question.
@Charlie no, you are not wrong. But we never use notations like $\frac{\nabla}{\nabla x^i}$ so never write that anywhere. 

I got what you meant though.

Comment: Ok I am familiar with vector being (to my understanding) maps such that $V:C^\infty (M) \rightarrow \Bbb R$, so when we write $V(f)$ we really just meant the directional derivative of the scalar function?

Also responding to the above, thank you I'm glad I at least have that right.

Comment: @Charlie yes to the second question, same thing. Writing in term of action of a vector on a functions makes for some neat math when manipulating those objects...but nonetheless, same thing dressed up in fancy notation.

Comment: Thank you for making that clear, just in reference to what AccidentalFourierTransform has written above, should I read the statement $\nabla_{a+b} = \nabla_{a} + \nabla_{b}$ as "the covariant directional derivative of whatever comes next in the direction (a+b) is given by the covariant derivative in the direction a plus the derivative in the direction b?

Comment: You’ve left out a $T$.

Comment: @Defcon97 Please refrain from answering questions in the comments.  Perhaps you could collect what you've written into an answer?

Comment: The AWOL T is back

Comment: @Murray you are right i did not intend to give a full answer but as i kept typing it turned out that way. I will collect my comments in an answer asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the first question we are basically doing a basis decomposition of the operator $\nabla_V$, so what we are saying is basically that it is equal to a linear combination of the operators $\nabla_{\hat{e}_\nu}$ and the components $V_ν$ in the formula are just the coefficients of this expansion.

for the second question it all boils down to definitions. Usually the Tangent space on a manifold $M$ is defined as the space of all the functions from $\mathcal{C}^∞(M)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that adhere to Leibniz's derivation law (the product law for derivatives). I understand it is not a very intuitive way to define it and there is no simple way to convince you that this definition is good other than directing you to a differential geometry textbook sadly, you'll have to take my word on that one. 
With this definition then the expression says exactly what you were expecting, namely that the action of the covariant derivative on a scalar field is just the action of the vector $X$ on the field, and that action happens to actually be the directional derivative of the field along $X$. It's just fancy notation that actually makes the whole thing really clear for people who like algebra. But fancy notation nonetheless